# apply a function in printf on scala

Tags: scala, vector

I receive in the method printfields a vector[String] which I am printing as follows:

```
def printFields(fields: Vector[String]): Unit =
{
  printf(fields.map(_ => "%s").mkString("",",","\n"),fields: _*)
  println(fields)

}
```

now this give me as output the following:

```
39,39,35,30
Vector(39, 39, 35,30)
28,28,35,30
Vector(28, 28, 35,30)
```

Now, Each number correspond to an Id, I need to apply a function to each number that appear here in order to print the element that correspond, in other words, make something like:

```
printf(fields.map(_ => "%s").mkString("",",","\n"),con.convI2N((fields: _*).toInt))
```

I try with converting the function to an Iterator, but give me Strings like

```
39
39
35,30
```

The last String can not be converted toInt, then this is not an option, 
Someone can help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about converting the `Vector[String]` to a `Vector[Int]` as preliminary operation?

```scala
fields.map(_.split(',')).flatten.map(_.toInt)
```

This is just an hint, it is not the safer way, you should check that every `String` in your `Vector` is actually an `Int` or a sequence of comma-separated `Int`s.

Comment: that is one of the problems that I have, I have some values like 35,30 that are not int, Do you have another clue?